# How to get selected Row data on edit link click in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with two extra buttons as Edit and Add on each row and I have a click event on each Edit and Add Linkbuttons through which I am opening a ModelViewExtender Dialog. I want when I am clicking on these linkbuttons on each row of gridview, all row data should accessed means Row Data of particular column (**cells**)from  the row of clicked Edit link.
You can get better understanding thorough the below image of GridView, as:

[image]

Please suggest me any solution regarding the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide the markup of your gridview?

Answer (score 0):

You have tow ways, either you use the AutoGenereateEdit property to true which will generate these hyperlinks. then on the row editing event you can get all these values easily by using the "e.NewEditIndex" which is the rowIndex of the GridViewRow your editing.

The second way is that you have put these hyperlinks "edit" and "add" as templates, in order to access them you need to parse the the sender object to it's control on the hyperlink click event and then get it's parent which will return the GridViewRow that the control on, which will allow you to get all the values you want from that row like this:

```
//Debug it and just make sure that tow parents return the GridViewRow
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((HyperLink)(sender)).Parent.Parent);
```